# Concatenar valores resultado de un INNER JOIN en un string separados por comas en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, tsql

Tengo el siguiente esquema en SQL Server 2012:

```
Tabla 1

Id INT PRIMARY KEY
Descripcion NVARCHAR(20)
Tipo INT

Tabla 2
Id INT PRIMARY KEY
Nombre NVARCHAR(80)
IdTabla1 INT --Llave foranea a la primera tabla

Tabla 3
Id INT PRIMARY KEY
Nombre NVARCHAR(80)
IdTabla1 INT --Llave foranea a la primera tabla
```

lo que necesito es formular una query para tener los valores de la tabla uno y los valores de la tabla 2 y tabla 3 en un campo separado por comas (,). Ej.

```
Tabla 1

Id   |  Descripcion | Tipo

1    |  'Descripcion prueba 1' |  0

2    |  'Descripcion prueba 2' |  2
```

Tabla 2

```
Id   |  Descripcion | IdTabla1

1    |  'ABC' |  1

2    |  'DEF' |  1

3    |  'HIJ' |  2
```

Tabla 3

```
Id   |  Descripcion | IdTabla1

1    |  '123' |  1

2    |  '456' |  2

3    |  '789' |  2
```

Resultado esperado por la consulta:

```
   Id   |  Descripcion | Tipo | ValoresTabla2 | ValoresTabla3

   1  |   'Descripcion prueba 1' | 0 | 'ABC,DEF' | '123'

   2  |   'Descripcion prueba 2' | 2 | 'HIJ' | '456,789'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar [`FOR XML PATH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178107.aspx) para concatenar los valores con coma y luego [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188043.aspx) para remover la coma de más en frente.

```
select t1.id, t1.descripcion, t1.tipo,
       stuff((select ',' + t2.nombre
                from table2 t2
               where t2.IdTabla1 = t1.id
               order by t2.id
                 for xml path('')),1,1,'') as ValoresTabla2,
       stuff((select ',' + t3.nombre
                from table3 t3
               where t3.IdTabla1 = t1.id
               order by t3.id
                 for xml path('')),1,1,'') as ValoresTabla3
  from table1 t1
 order by t1.id;
```

[Demostración](http://rextester.com/HKLT89725).